# Integrating TinyMCE Filebrowser/Imagebrowser with FTP Support

Tags: php, ftp, tinymce

Has anybody built a custom tinymce mcefilemanager with ftp support or tried to integrate an ftp mount?

There are many questions in the forums about this but no solutions.
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4987

Altough Spocke (the admin) responds to one of the questions:

> We recommend mapping ftps as drives using mount points or similar since PHP has issues keeping connections to the server open. And that would reduce the speed alot.

I have no idea on how to do this? Anybody experienced with creating mounts on ftp? How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a step-by-step tutorial](http://www.linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem) howto achieve this for unix systems.

For windows you may want to have [a look at this tutorial.](http://www.lalitkapoor.com/blog/2008/06/29/mount-ftp-or-sftp-as-a-drive-in-windows/)

Comment: Is it possible to do this dynamically with php?

Comment: hmmm, not an elegant way, but you may use the "exec" command in order tu run OS-based system commands.